# How to specify some object with optional enum keys with correct IDE suggestions

Tags: typescript, object, enums

I have enums for possible icons names and sizes

```js
enum IconName {
  icon1 = "icon1",
  icon2 = "icon2",
}

enum IconSize {
  s1 = "s1",
  s2 = "s2",
}

type IconConfig = {
  source: number;
  size: IconSize;
};
```

How should I type iconsSet for correct IDE suggestions?

```js
const iconsSet: Record<IconName, Partial<Record<IconSize, IconConfig>>> = {
  icon1: {
    s1: {
      source: 0,
      size: IconSize.s1
    }
  },
  icon2: {
    s1: {
      source: 0,
      size: IconSize.s1
    },
    s2: {
      source: 0,
      size: IconSize.s2
    },
  },
};
```

For example, I want to see only s1 for icon1
[image]
but s1 and s2 for icon2
[image]